# When does the cpu actually come online?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have been working with Linux Kernel 4.19.2.

In some of the functions e.g. [generic_exec_single()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/kernel/smp.c#L141), it is required to have a cpu online. It is checked by the function [cpu_online()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/include/linux/cpumask.h#L103).

However I tried by printing the output of the cpu_online() function at various stages for example, the dmesg output at time 0.27 gives 0 while the same at time 0.33 gives a 1.

The output seemed inconsistent as I feel all the cpus should be online even before the first task. Isn't it so?

What exactly is meant by a cpu being online? And when is that state achieved as the system boots up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, going through the kernel code, it can be figured out that there is a difference between cores being powered up and the kernel 'announcing' them to be online. It does it with the functions [do_boot_cpu()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L963) and [announce_cpu()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L841).